# jest.spyOn component property

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs

Can `jest.spyOn` component property?
I need to make sure `isLoading` is always `true`

```js
export default {  
  data() {
    return {     
      isLoading: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async loadData() {
      this.isLoading = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't spy on a data property, but you don't really need to in this case.

Instead, you could stub out `loadData()`, and mount the component with the initial value for `isLoading`:

1. Set `MyComponent.methods.loadData` to `jest.fn()` to stub it out.
2. Mount the component with an initial `data()` property, returning `true` for the `isLoading` property.

```js
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyComponent from '@/components/MyComponent.vue'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  it('sets isLoading', () => {
    1️⃣
    MyComponent.methods.loadData = jest.fn()

    const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      2️⃣
      data() {
        return {
          isLoading: true,
        }
      },
    })

    expect(wrapper.vm.isLoading).toBe(true)
    expect(wrapper.text()).toContain('Loading...')
  })
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-test-loading-flag?file=tests%2Funit%2FMyComponent.spec.js)